# Overleaf's autocompile keeps turning off

Tags: overleaf

I'm using Overleaf and Mozilla Firefox. I usually leave the autocompile on as I type. However, as I type, Overleaf disables autocompile, the compiled PDF on the viewing pane disappears and is replaced with the message

> Sorry, something went wrong and your project could not be compiled.
> Please try again in a few moments.

I have to then manually turn on autocompile again. Is there any way to stop this from happening as it happens every few minutes.

Other points:

1. I'm using a free account.
2. The project is not shared and I do not have multiple machines/tabs with Overleaf open.

Comment: this is a level of service query about overleaf, you should contact their support (who can see the back end of your project so be more helpful) it's not really on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Is your code very heavy and does it contain a lot of images/graphics? In Overleaf you only have one minute to compile for free accounts.

Sometimes when you use TikZ and you are missing ";" it tends to take a long time to compile and after the minute it throws the message you mention.

Comment: This seems to be a comment, not an answer.